# What are the spare wires seen in the attic, if not for lighting?

Tags: electrical, wiring, attic

I am trying to understand where all the T&E wires in my attic go to.

I have 3 rooms (Bedroom, office, spare room) on the 1st floor (below the attic), plus a hallway near the stairs. All the wires running to the sockets in the first floor come from underneath.

I have worked out the first-floor lighting wiring as shown below - CU represents the consumer unit, L is just a shorthand for Lighting ceiling rose. Anything below the ceiling (green) line goes into the different rooms.
[image]

However I don't understand the extra T&E wires lying around in the attic as shown below. The violet horizontal lines are used to indicate that the earths of the respective T&E wires are tied together above the ceiling.
[image]

- The red line represents 2 T&E wires; one from the bedroom and the other from the hallway tied via the earths above the ceiling; live and neutral wires are just left dangling in the attic.
- The white lines going between rooms represent T&E wires.

Question: Where do these wires (ones represented by the white lines and the red lines in the 2nd image) go to, below the ceiling if not to the lights, light switches or sockets?

I'm in the UK.

Images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: If only used to connect grounds, I would think older wires without a ground between the two.  I know that across the pond here, they adjusted the electric code to allow people to add a separate ground wire to provide ground to ungrounded devices, instead of needing a new cable with live/neutral and ground.  They used a cable with ground, instead of just a ground?

Comment: Objective? Because nothing I would do begins or ends with any of that. Start over from the load center.

Comment: @crip659 - Interesting. Perhaps I've got my assumption wrong that the wires are T&E. I have now attached pictures - please let me know if you both see anything obvious in the pictures. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mazura - My objective is just to understand the wiring, so I can then tidy them up before boarding the attic. May I know how you define load center in this scenario? Many thanks.

Comment: Load center = breaker box (for adding e.g., a new outlet). - "tidy them up" Drop the power, disconnect them, and then put them back *exactly* as they were (w/o being tangled / crossed over each other - or not; just jam 'em up there and put hangers). Because, no clue. - 1st pic; can't do anything. 2nd pic, can't do much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realistically, nobody can tell without systematically tracing where each wire goes.

The wiring looks pretty shoddy anyway.  There are red and black cores exposed, not inside any sort of enclosure (such as a junction box), and the earths are twisted together without anything resembling a terminal block to ensure good contact.